# how do you install a glass door on a drywall?

Tags: drywall

I have made a cabinet style cutout in the drywall and finished with dry wall.  Now I want to install a glass door to this drywall and want to know how and best way to do it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

Gypsum board will not support a glass door, unless the door is tiny (like a 6" square).

You will need a frame which goes all around the opening and is secured to a structural member, like a stud. Then the door is attached with hinges to the frame and a latch or latches are installed on the other side of the frame.

Answer (score 0):

With a piano hinge.
And a 2 or 3mm shim to keep it from rubbing on the wall.
Not sure how to mount the hinge to the glass though.

Comment: generally we would like to see answers more complete, with full details